# Integrate function with cumulative distibution function inside

Tags: scipy, quadrature

I'm trying to integrate a function which is defined as `func` in my code below, a cumulative distribution function is inside:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math
import numpy as np


def func(v, r):
    return (1 - norm.cdf(r / math.sqrt(v)))

print(quad(lambda x: func(x, 1) , 0, np.inf))
```

and I get this warning:

> IntegrationWarning: The algorithm does not converge.  Roundoff error is detected
> in the extrapolation table.  It is assumed that the requested tolerance
> cannot be achieved, and that the returned result (if full_output = 1) is
> the best which can be obtained.

and the result is:

```
(1465037253.745132, 2713580385.6787577)
```

I think that this result is wrong, but I don't know what to change in my code. I tried to exclude point 0, but that didn't help.

I tried also to change limit to try not from 0, but from r (so in attached example from 1) (these are different results that I need to check) and there is different error:

> IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.

And also I think that obtained results is wrong. Do you have any advice?

EDIT:

I'm trying to calculate this:

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty 1 - G(r/\sqrt v)\, dv$

where G(x) is the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Can you add the function that you want to integrate using MathJax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SE!
For growing x, your function converges to `1-norm.cdf(0)`, which is $1-0.5=0.5$. Consequently, the integral is indeed divergent, just like Python told you;)